# Async/await function in mongoose

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-games')
    .then(() => console.log('Now connected to MongoDB!'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err));

const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    publisher: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    onSale: Boolean,
    price: Number
});

const Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);

async function saveGame() {
    const game = new Game({
        title: "The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild",
        publisher: "Nintendo",
        tags: ["adventure", "action"],
        onSale: false,
        price: 59.99,
    });

    const result = await game.save();
    console.log(result);
}

saveGame();
```

My doubt about the code is that : how in this code async/await function is used. What is use of that. Can we not make this without using them.

SOurce : https://vegibit.com/mongoose-crud-tutorial/

Comment: It is used here for the `console.log(result)`. Without the await, the console.log would output a pending Promise. Now, it will output the result (resolved Promise). Alternatively, you could use `.then()` on the Promise if you want to avoid using async/await, just like with `mongoose.connect`.

Comment: @Tom ANd how can we know it uses a promise function

Comment: If you check Mongoose's documentation (on `save()`), you'll know it returns a Promise.